# Optional route params with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my Vue 2.7.5 app (using Vue Router 3.5.4) I'm trying to define this route

```
{
  path: '/messages/:messageId?/replies/:replyId?',
  name: 'messages',
  component: () => import('@/views/messages')
}
```

The intent is

- to see all messages use `/messages`
- to see a specific message use `/messages/:messageId`
- To see a specific message and a specific reply to that message use `/messages/:messageId/replies/:replyId`

However, if I navigate to this route without specifying any route params using

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'messages'}">
```

Then the URL is resolved as `/messages/replies`, but I would like it to be resolved as `/messages`.

Essentially, what I want is: don't include `/replies` unless there's a `replyId` param, but I don't know how to express that.

One solution is to use the following instead:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/messages'}">
```

But I prefer to always refer to routes by name, because this gives me the flexibility to change the paths without breaking anything

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for you is to remove /replies and only have path like this:
`'/messages/:messageId?/:replyId?'`

(Optional solution)
If removing that part of url is not an option and using named routes is a must, here is an alternative solution where you use two named routes. If the replyId is missing you can redirect before enter to the 2nd named route.

```
{
    path: '/messages/:messageId?/replies/:replyId?',
    name: 'message-replies',
    component: () => import('@/views/messages'),
    beforeEnter({ params }) {
      if (!params.replyId) {
        return {
          name: 'messages',
          params: {
            messageId: params.messageId,
          },
        };
      }
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/messages/:messageId?',
    name: 'messages',
    component: () => import('@/views/messages'),
  },
```